# How to find values of the input data in plotsommaphits

Tags: matlab, cluster-computing, identification, som

I have used SOM tool box in MATLAB or iris data set. following example and using the plotsomhits i can see that how many data values are in each neuron of my neuron grid of the  SOM . However I wish to know actual data  values which are grouped in every neuron of the given SOM configuration .Is there any way to do it. this is the example I used.

```
net = selforgmap([8 8]);
view(net)
[net,tr] = train(net,x);
nntraintool
plotsomhits(net,x)
```

Answer (score 0):

not that hard. `plotsomhits` just plots "fancily" the results of the simulation of the net.

so if you simulate it and add the "hits" you have the result!

basicaly:

```
hits=sum(sim(net,x)');
```

In your net case this was my results, that coincide with the numbers in the `plotsomehits`

```
hits= 6     5     0     7    15     7     4     0     8    20     3     3     9     3     0     8     6     3    11     4     5     5     7    10     1
```

PD: you can learn a lot in this amazing SO answer:

[MATLAB: help needed with Self-Organizing Map (SOM) clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686567/matlab-help-needed-with-self-organizing-map-som-clustering?rq=1)

Comment: thanks Ander, However as I understand from your answer , please correct me if I am wrong in assuming that  the statement sum(sim(net,x)') will give sum of  all values clustered in a neuron. while i want to know what are values not their sum that are cluster to a single neuron

Comment: @Nhqazi their values are 1... In a NN in general each output is binary, telling you if the result is from that output or not. So 7, means that 7 different inputs correspond to that specific output. I dont know much about SOM, this is just basic NN.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert vector to indices first and then you can see what input values a neuron correspond to.

```
>> input_neuron_mapping = vec2ind(net(x))';
```

Now, look into the neuron's inputs.

For example, you want to see neuron input values for neuron 2.

```
>> neuron_2_input_indices = find(input_neuron_mapping == 2)
>> neuron_2_input_values = x(neuron_2_input_indices)
```

It will display all the input values from your data.

Read here for more details:
https://bioinformaticsreview.com/20220603/how-to-get-input-values-from-som-sample-hits-plot-in-matlab/